# How do you run many SQL commands against an Azure SQL database using an Azure Automation powershell runbook

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-automation

I'm using Azure Automation to move an Azure SQL database from one resource to another(from Prod to Dev for example).  After the database is copied, I would then like to run SQL script that adds some users and permissions. This would mean I need to run a handful of commands like "Create user..." and "alter role....". Most examples I've found use powershell to execute a single SQL command, but using that code to run many commands seems like it would result in an excessively long powershell script. In the on-prem world, I probably would have .sql file that gets executed. Any suggestions on how to achieve this easily using powershell in Azure Automation. Thanks!

Comment: You didn't post any code but I assume you are using `Invoke-SQL`? Looks like it has a parameter `-InputFile` that you can use. In the world of cloud this should probably point at a file sitting in blob storage. You might also want to consider using a VS database project if you want to get more sophisticated.

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid. Yes I should have mentioned that I tried using some typical powershell commandlets like Invoke-SQLCMD and Invoke-SQLCMD2, and the system.data.sqlcommand namespace. My issue with the Azure storage approach is that Azure Automation is not on the "trusted services" list for azure storage which isn't going to work for me with our organization's security practices. I'm also looking into Elastic Jobs (still in preview though) to do the SQL script execution, however I end up with two schedulers to get one workflow done and AFAIK, Azure Automation cannot call an Elastic job.

Comment: I'm pretty sure elastic jobs has been in preview for a long time. Is Azure Automation not being on the trusted list your only issue? This actually sounds like it could be a job for Azure DevOps. You'd still need to convince your enterprise to get it whitelisted etc. but it might be a little easier since you can have self hosted agents with fixed internal IP's. Azure DevOps could definitely do this using pipelines, it's pretty much made for this.

Comment: If you used Azure DevOps, you could keep your post db copy script in Git with all the good version control and security etc. You get a visual interface with logs and security to track the db deployment also.

Comment: why don't you create a stored procedure with all required commands in the DB you are copying and execute it using PowerShell runbook in Automation account? You would not need storage to store the script.